# Prevent windows to use physical network adapter used for virtual machine

Tags: windows, networking, vmware

I have pc with windows 10 and two physical network adapters. One is for corporate/domain network and second for internet connection. I have virtual pc with vmware and i want use this internet adapter for it. But i want to block my physical pc to use it for any connection. When i disable it (this network adapter) on my pc i can not use it in vmware. Is there some way to prevent pc use this adapter and still be able to use it in vmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some way to prevent pc use this adapter and still be able to
> use it in VMware?

Virtual (guest) machines are dependent on host hardware for the guest machine operations.

So then if you disable host resources, a VMware machine will not see the disabled resources.

This is normal.  (I am using VMware V16 here).

The way to possibly solve it is to get a USB Ethernet Adapter and enable this Adapter in the VMware guest machine by using USB Passthrough.  VMware supports this.

Now set up the driver for the Adapter in your guest machine and connect it to the particular resource you want.

When pass through is active, the host machine will not use the USB adapter.